# Do you gain points back when deleting question/answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It happens sometimes; you answer or ask a question, but people don't like it. You get downvotes. Hiding your head in shame, you delete your post, so that no one knows about this. Do you get your points back/lose points you've gained?

Comment: I love the narrative.  :D  Although in an ideal world, you wouldn't delete a downvoted answer because it was unpopular/shameful, but because (and only *if*) it contained misleading or inaccurate information.  That's highly theoretical, of course.

Comment: @Wildcard In theory there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly yes, deleting a post nullifies any reputation changes caused by votes cast on it. More details are given in [the community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/203101):

> Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, [is retained](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)).
>
> - Reputation lost as a penalty for having a post deleted by flagging is not returned.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was not aware of these exceptions. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @FaheemMitha up to you